# kernel density shows normal residuals distribution

Tags: statistics

having run a regression I check the estimated kernel density of the residuals. They appear nearly normal.

What can I conclude based on this? Can I say that my regression is 'good' in some sense as a result?

Answer (score 0):

In regression analysis, it is always a good idea to do all you can to
assess the validity of the underlying assumptions, including: random sampling, common variance, normal errors.

One way, perhaps not the best, to check whether errors are
normally distributed is to to look at a density estimator. So your observation
that the KDE of residuals looks normal is *one indication* the regression analysis meets assumptions and may be useful. Ideally, that would not be the end of
your 'regression diagnostics'.